# My web-crawler with node.js didn't display the expected output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

Here is my web-crawler with `node.js` using `cheerio` library:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
var urls = [];

request('http://www.reddit.com', function(err, resp, body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('a.title may-blank').each(function(){
            var url = this.attr('href');
            urls.push(url);
        });
        console.log(urls);
    }
});
```

But when I run it I get the the following output:

```
[]
```

Instead of 25 links in the array.

**What have I done wrong?**

**How can I fix that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing `may-blank` is a class, so you need a `.` in front of it:

```
$('a.title .may-blank').each(...
// Here ---^
```

...although at present, `a.title .may-blank` doesn't match any elements on the reddit front page for me; there are no `.may-blank` elements that are *descendants* of `a.title`.

If you wanted `a` elements that have both the class `title` **and** has the class `may-blank`, remove the space before `.may-blank`; for me there are currently 36 of those:

```
$('a.title.may-blank').each(...
//        ^-- no space
```

Or just `.may-blank` matches 167.

Comment: now I am getting this error: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'attr'`

Comment: @MichaelVayvala: That would be a *different* question. (And are you sure you didn't want `$(this).attr(...)`? That would be what it would be with jQuery; last time I used Cheerio, though, it was slightly different from jQuery in terms of what it did with `this`...)

Answer (score -1):

There is a little tpyo if I am not mistaking, the tag selector should be 'title may-blank ', notice the space after the blank, or you should change the selector to '^⁼' starts with to be more forgiven, hope that will help.

Comment: my bad, didn't pay attention the selector type, it was a class !